# Android - Get time after 2 hours

Tags: java, android, time

In my Android app. I am running  some Task every 2 hours.How can i check that the time has exceeded 2 hours.

I tried to use this but it says depreceated

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2);
```

I would appreciate the insight on how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link

http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/comparing-date-time-values-in-android-t1567.html

```
Calendar current_time = Calendar.getInstance ();
current_time.add(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
current_time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
current_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 
//Subtract 2 hours       
current_time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)-2);
current_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
current_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar given_time = Calendar.getInstance ();
given_time.set(Calendar.YEAR, syear);
//Give the day sDay and hour shour
given_time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, sday);
given_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, shour);
given_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
given_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Date current_calendar = current_time.getTime();
Date given_calendar = given_time.getTime();

System.out.println("Current Calendar "+ current_calendar);
System.out.println("Given Calendar "+ given_calendar);

boolean v = current_calendar.after(given_calendar); 

if(v){

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Link in answer is dead (404).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `Calendar` class.

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2);
calendar.getTime();//your date +2 hours
```

Answer (score 2):

use [**Calendar class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)>(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+2));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is deprecated. Use `Calendar` instead.

Source: [Java: Why is the Date constructor deprecated, and what do I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-date-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Two hours is 2 * 60 minutes, is 2 * 60 * 60 seconds and is 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds.  So you can just add this number of milliseconds to your date:

```
Date date = new Date ();
Date after2Hours = new Date (date.getTime () + 2L * 60L * 60L * 1000L);
```

Comment: Use of Date() class is deprecated!

Comment: @PradeepSimha Are you sure?  Class Date is not marked as deprecated in my JDK (Oracle JDK 1.7.0_13 x64).

Comment: Deprecated since ~10years? Eclipse with ADT wil mark it as deprecated.

Comment: Date class isn't deprecated, some behaviour of this class is deprecated after the introduction of Calender

Comment: Quote from the API : ` As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding methods in Date are deprecated.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to repeat that task every two hours, you should use Alarm manager service for that. See the link below for more details.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html