# how to format 2013-05-15T10:00:00-07:00 to Date android

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to format the date string to Date, and then get the month/day from it:

```
String strDate="2013-05-15T10:00:00-07:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-z");

    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 SimpleDateFormat sdfmonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
        String monthday= sdfmonth.format(convertedDate);
```

but it returns me current month/day i.e 5/18. Whats wrong?

Comment: because you get the ParseException, and convertDate is initialized with today date

Comment: try with this pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-z"

Comment: Does the stacktrace print? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(convertedDate);` inside that try block.. Post us what you get or stack trace if there is exception...

Comment: You get a bad date because you should re-format convertedDate in the try block. Actually you do it even if your block raisde an exception.

Comment: @SohailAziz I tried with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" and worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 things :

- There is a mistake in your format : 2013-05-15T10:00:00-07:00 has no meaning, it should be 2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700 (with no colon at the end, this is a timezone defined in RFC 822. (Look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) about Z).
- Change your format to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ as mentionned by @blackbelt
- you get a bad date because you re-format your date whatever happens during parsing. Re-format in your try block, if and only if parsing worked.

----------Update

```
    String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfmonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
        String monthday = sdfmonth.format(convertedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700` this string also thows me Unparseable exception friend.

Comment: I tried this with latest android sdk. It worked. I aspected It will not, but Actually It worked (with yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ). Any clues?

Comment: Sorry friend this one runs perfectly. Itried with `new SimpleDateFormat(
"MMMM d, yyyy")`. That is problem I think.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is wrong in your code. for me it throws Unparseable exception like this.

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-05-15T10:00:00-07:00"`

But the following way works well.

```
String strDate="January 2, 2010";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
System.out.println(date.getMonth());
```

But in java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-date-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead) as per http://docs.oracle.com/ . Try to use [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of Date.

I hope this will help you.