# java.util.Date(int,int,int) deprecated

Tags: java

The constructor `java.util.Date(int,int,int)` is deprecated. Is there a way to set a date easy as that in Java? What's the non-deprecated way to do this?

```
Date date = new Date(2015, 3, 2);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What's the non-deprecated way to do this?

Java 8 to the rescue:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 2);
```

And then if you really really need a `java.util.Date`, you can use the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simplest-conversion).

For more info, check out [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or [the tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) for Java 8.

Answer (score 7):

By using

> java.util.Calendar

is one possibility:

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 28);
   Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Keep in mind that months are 0 based, so January is 0-th month and december 11th.

Answer (score 3):

Try Calendar.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date =  calendar.getTime();
```

I am sure there also is a method which takes the values you provide in your example.

Comment: This class is singleton. What if I want to change the date and store different dates e.g. inside a database?

Comment: Oh, or is it singleton? ^^

Comment: I don't get your point ...

Comment: It would be a problem if it was singleton but the docu says it isn't so your suggestion is good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Calendar class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), specifically the set(int year, int month, int date) for your purpose. This is from Java 7, but you'll have equivalent - setDate(), setYear() etc. - methods in older versions.