# LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simplest conversion?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

Is there a simple way to convert a `LocalDate` (introduced with Java 8) to `java.util.Date` object?

By 'simple', I mean simpler than this:

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

which seems a bit awkward to me.

Since we are interested only in the date portion and there is no timezone information in neither of the objects, why introduce time zones explicitly? The midnight time and the system default timezone should be taken implicitly for the conversion.

Comment: If youre using Java 8 you should probably avoid `java.util.Date` altogether

Comment: "Since we are interested only in the date portion" problem is that `java.util.Date` by default is expected not only to represent informations about day (year/month/day), but also about time of day so we need to somehow provide this informations (here helps `atStartOfDay`).

Comment: A `LocalDate` is **not** an instant in time, it is a _date_, such as "30 Jan 2014". It is not tied to any particular instant _until you give it a time zone_. I'm not entirely sure you understand what you are asking...

Comment: A Date represents a precise instant. A LocalDate doesn't. It's just a set of fields. You thus need to specify a timezone to transform this set of fields to an instant: 2015-10-11T00:00 is not the same instant in Paris and in New York.

Comment: @Reimeus Actually that is the case. As I am using the new java time api, there are APIs (e.g. JDBC) which takes dates and times from java.util or java.sql packages. Hence the required conversion.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not certain that that's the easiest way to understand it.  Both `Date` and `Instant` are internally reckoned in UTC and (thankfully) have no notion of local time zone.  `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` are intended to represent their respective temporal values in arbitrary local time zones which most of the time are not UTC.  Hence there is no simple, historically consistent way to directly convert from one form to the other without knowing more information.

Comment: @Reimeus: if he's using an older API, then he may have no choice but to use `Date`.  The `@Basic` annotation of JPA 2.1, for example, directly recognizes `Date` and `Calendar` but will only work with `Instant` as a serializable type.  I would say he's doing the right thing by using the new Date-Time API in his new code and using `Date` to interoperate.

Comment: *"Since we are interested only in the date portion and there is no timezone information in neither of the objects why introduce time zones here?"* ... you may think there is no time zone here, but there always is whenever (whenever) there is a notion of time.  The timestamps "07-Sep-2015T17:30" and "07-Sep-2015T22:30" in U.S. Central Daylight Time have the same dates locally but different dates in UTC (and, therefore, different dates as Instants).

Comment: @George: the general contract for `Date` and `Instant` both include the notion of time.  Interconverting between `LocalDate` and `Date` therefore means that you are necessarily dealing with a notion of time, even if you don't intend to use time information.  You can't convert from "07-Sept-2015 in some local time zone" (`LocalDate`) to "milliseconds since midnight 01-Jan-1970 UTC" (`Date`) without knowing what "some local time zone" is.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

## tl;dr

> Is there a simple way to convert a LocalDate (introduced with Java 8) to java.util.Date object? By 'simple', I mean simpler than this

Nope. You did it properly, and as concisely as possible.

```
java.util.Date.from(                     // Convert from modern java.time class to troublesome old legacy class.  DO NOT DO THIS unless you must, to inter operate with old code not yet updated for java.time.
    myLocalDate                          // `LocalDate` class represents a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone nor offset-from-UTC. 
    .atStartOfDay(                       // Let java.time determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone. Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00.
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )  // Specify time zone using proper name in `continent/region` format, never 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as “PST”, “CST”, “IST”. 
    )                                    // Produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
    .toInstant()                         // Extract an `Instant` object, a moment always in UTC.
)
```

Read below for issues, and then think about it. How could it be simpler? If you ask me what time does a date start, how else could I respond but ask you “Where?”?. A new day dawns earlier in Paris FR than in Montréal CA, and still earlier in Kolkata IN, and even earlier in Auckland NZ, all different moments.

So in converting a date-only (`LocalDate`) to a date-time we *must* apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a zoned value (`ZonedDateTime`), and then move into UTC (`Instant`) to match the definition of a `java.util.Date`.

## Details

Firstly, avoid the old legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` whenever possible. They are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They were supplanted by the java.time classes for a reason, actually, for *many* reasons.

But if you must, you can convert to/from java.time types to the old. Look for new conversion methods added to the old classes.

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## `java.util.Date` → `java.time.LocalDate`

Keep in mind that a `java.util.Date` is a misnomer as it represents a date *plus* a time-of-day, in UTC. In contrast, the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Going from `java.util.Date` to java.time means converting to the equivalent class of `java.time.Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

So we need to move that `Instant` into a time zone. We apply `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

From there, ask for a date-only, a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

## `java.time.LocalDate` → `java.util.Date`

To move the other direction, from a `java.time.LocalDate` to a `java.util.Date` means we are going from a date-only to a date-time. So we must specify a time-of-day. You probably want to go for the first moment of the day. Do *not* assume that is `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means the first moment may be another time such as `01:00:00`. Let java.time determine that value by calling `atStartOfDay` on the `LocalDate`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDate.atStartOfDay( z );
```

Now extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Convert that `Instant` to `java.util.Date` by calling [`from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

## More info

- [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)
- Similar Question, [Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706)

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I like this answer because it contains both the tl and the dr part, thanks

Answer (score 145):

**Disclaimer:** While the answer below works, it is not recommended to be used in production code. The approach in the Basil's answer should be followed in this case.

Actually there is. There is a static method [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-) in the `java.sql.Date` object which does exactly that. So we have

```
java.util.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

and that's it. No explicit setting of time zones because the local time zone is taken implicitly.

From docs:

> The provided LocalDate is interpreted as the local date in the local
> time zone.

The `java.sql.Date` subclasses `java.util.Date` so the result is a `java.util.Date` also.

And for the reverse operation there is a [toLocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) method in the java.sql.Date class. So we have:

`LocalDate ld = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()).toLocalDate();`

Comment: The original question Date is also in system timezone. Using java.sql.Date for a actual date is not that far fetched, IMHO.

Comment: This answer can NOT be recommended because a) it lacks support for different timezones and b) mix up two different types where the inheritance relationship only denotes an implementation-driven dependency. The type `java.sql.Date` should only be applied in context of JDBC. Best answer see that from @Basil Bourque

Comment: As Hochschild said, the class doc tells us to ignore the inheritance subclass relationship between java.util.Date & java.sql.Date, tells us to *not* do what this Answer does. Furthermore that `valueOf` method does *not* skirt the issue of time zone, it merely *hides* the issue while silently applying the JVM’s current default zone in setting the time-of-day to midnight. So the statement “No time zones, no complications” is **incorrect**: There *are* time zones involved, and there *are* complications, you've just chosen to ignore them. The java.time classes were invented for a reason; use them.

Comment: As the author of the `java.time.*` libraries I am saddened that over 40 people have seen fit to upvote this. The correct answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/38896) and Basil's below. Using `java.sql.Date` is a horrible hack as expressed in other comments and this approach hides the time-zone conversion, which is a Bad Thing. It has also been known for years that `java.sql.Date` should never have extended `java.util.Date`. Finally, when using modules in Java 9, the `java.sql` classes will be a separate dependency, so using this hack will have consequences.

Comment: @JodaStephen I think the problem lies with old JDBC APIs which pass back `java.sql.Dates` which can then easily be cast down to `java.util.Date` by unsuspecting intermediate classes and then when you call `java.util.Date::toInstant()`, you get an `UnsupportedOperationException` from `java.sql.Date` :(

Comment: Its a hack at best. Please ignore this answer. And instead see @BasilBourque's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40143687/468763)

Answer (score 30):

Date -> LocalDate:

```
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

LocalDate -> Date:

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: if your `java.util.Date` is actually a `java.sql.Date`, then this will give you an `UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 5):

**Converting LocalDateTime to java.util.Date**

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());

    Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();

    Date date = Date.from(instant);

System.out.println("Result Date is : "+date);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Date to LocalDate**

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

**LocalDate to Date**

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this question with solution below

```
  import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
  Date myDate = new Date();
  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.fromDateFields(myDate);
  System.out.println("My date using Date" Nov 18 11:23:33 BRST 2016);
  System.out.println("My date using joda.time LocalTime" 2016-11-18);
```

In this case localDate print your date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Typo? Did you mean to pass `date` rather than `data`?

Comment: Please cite the documentation for that method. I do not see that method on the [class doc for `java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: My bad. My bad. I forgot copy the variable.

Comment: You can edit your Answer to correct the typo. And clarify the source of that method you used. Seems to be from Joda-Time, but this Question is about `java.time.LocalDate`. The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to java.time.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque for your observation.
In this case i used the class LocalDate of package: org.joda.time

Fixing the answer

I solved this issue with the solution below:

`import org.joda.time.LocalDate
Date myDate = new Date ();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.fromDateFields (myDate);

System.out.println("My date using Date" Nov 18 11:23:33 BRST 2016);
System.out.println("My date using joda.time LocalTime" 2016-11-18);
`

Comment: I suggest this other answer available in this stack:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate

In this case was used the class of org.time.LocalDate.

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its team advises migration to the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7 use the ThreeTen-Backport project.

Answer (score -5):

You can convert the `java.util.Date` object into a `String` object, which will format the date as yyyy-mm-dd.

LocalDate has a `parse` method that will convert it to a `LocalDate` object. The string must represent a valid date and is parsed using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.

**Date to LocalDate**

```
LocalDate.parse(Date.toString())
```

Comment: You have obivously not tested your code suggestion, otherwise you would have seen an exception because `java.time.LocalDate` expects an ISO-formatted string, not the std-output of `java.util.Date`. Deserves a downvote, but today I have a good day ;-) The best answer here is given by Basil Bourque.