# how to replace the deprecated constructor Date(int, int, int) in JAVA GWT?

Tags: java, date, gwt, calendar

I'm working on an existing GWT app . I'm seeing this warning

> the constructor Date(int, int, int) is deprecated

Since java.util.Calendar is not supported in GWT client side , I'm looking for how to replace this methode .

Comment: If you can use Java 8, [this reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) has some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no replacement for GWT (for now at least, `java.time` support/emulation should come some time in the future). Just put `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` if you want to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score -2):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-date-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead) will help answer your question.

You can use the `Calendar.set()` and `Calendar.get()` methods to set/get the date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Calendar` is not available in the [subset of JRE](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) that GWT supports on the client side.

Answer (score -2):

Use always Calendar (GregorianCalendar would suit what you need). And when you need to turn it into a Date object, use Calendar.getTime()

This page has examples:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Comment: The question stated that Calendar is not supported by GWT, which uses a subset of the Java language.