# Why I obtain a wrong result when I create a new Date starting from the year, the month and the day in this Java application?

Tags: java, date

I have some problem trying to create a **Date** in Java, starting from the year, the month and the day.

So, I have created this simple utility method that creates my date:

```
private Date creaDataNascita(int birthYear, int birthMonth, int birthDay) {

    Date dataNascita = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);

    return dataNascita;

}
```

I have the following values for the input parameters (I checked it with the debugger.):

```
birthYear = 1984
birthMonth = 4
birthDay = 12
```

The problem is that this line:

```
Date dataNascita = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
```

creates me a strange date, its value in fact is: **12-mag-3884**.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: don't use the `Date` constructor - its deprecated and its evil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-the-date-constructor-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead

Comment: What does the java doc say?

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. Your question has been handled many times already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) Javadoc notes

> - A year `y` is represented by the integer `y - 1900`.
> - A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

To get the correct `Date` with the *deprecated* `Date` constructor, it would need to be something like `new Date(birthYear - 1900, birthMonth - 1, birthDay);` but I would prefer [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) like

```
int birthYear = 1984;
int birthMonth = 4;
int birthDay = 12;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
System.out.println(ld);
```

Output is

```
1984-04-12
```

Answer (score -1):

As said in the javadoc :

1. Date(int year, int month, int day)
   Deprecated. 
   instead use the constructor Date(long date)
2. Date(long date)
   Constructs a Date object using the given milliseconds time value.

Answer (score -1):

As referenced in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html,

The Date class is deprecated, Use **Calendar.set** instead.

Comment: What does it being deprecated have to do with the value it produces? Is the value random?

Comment: The `java.util.Date` class is *not* deprecated.  Many of its methods and constructors are, but the class itself is not.