# Deprecation while running an app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecation-warning

[image: Showing a cross on Date]

I am working in an Application to change and show the date but got a problem and the app crashes when the button is clicked. Here is the dialog from Android Studio Gradle Console:

> ```
> MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> ```

How may I solve it and what is the reason?

Comment: Check this StackOverflow question for details on Date deprecation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-the-date-constructor-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead. However, the deprecation is unrelated to your app crash problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Why is the Date constructor deprecated, and what do I use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-the-date-constructor-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 0):

The Date class is deprecated.

Use Calendar instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Incorrect. Most of the methods in [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are deprecated, but not the entire class. Practically speaking, Both `Date` and `Calendar` are supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: So finally I used this class and get rid of that problem. GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();  Thanks for the help