# How to calculate age and show birthday toast message every year

Tags: java, android, date

I am learning android development, and I want to show a notification for users who have birthday today based on their current location. I have a basic DatePicker that gets the date of birth from users using these codes:

```
String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
int monthValue = datePicker.getMonth();
String month = MONTHS[monthValue];
String dateofBirth = datePicker.getDayOfMonth() + " " + month + " " + datePicker.getYear();
```

the user date of birth that I got is in this string format:

```
24 Jan 1982
```

Is there a way to calculate user's birthday age using the date string format above and show a birthday notification on that day every year? For example:

```
"Today is your 37th birthday!"
```

I think this feature would be lovely but I don't know how to calculate it and compare it with today's date based on different location :(

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Generate text representing the date.

```
LocalDate                                    // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, using `java.time.LocalDate` class.
.of( 1982 , 1 , 24 )                         // Specify a date. Notice the sane numbering of both year and month, unlike the legacy classes `Date`/`Calendar`. Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.format(                                     // Generate text to represent the value of the `LocalDate` object.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )   // How long or abbreviated do you want the text.
    .withLocale( Locale.UK )                 // Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.
)                                            // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 24 Jan 1982

Calculate age.

```
Period
.between(
    LocalDate.of( 1982 , 1 , 24 ) ,
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) 
)
.getYears()
```

Birthday toast.

```
MonthDay
.now( 
    ZoneId.systemDefault()   // Specify time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.
)
.equals(
    MonthDay.of( 1 , 24 )
)
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

From your [`DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker), pull the year, month, and day, passing all three to the factory method for `LocalDate`.

```
DatePicker dp = … ;
…
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( dp.getYear() , dp.getMonth() , dp.getDayOfMonth() ) ;
```

You can define your own formatting pattern when generating text for presentation to the user. But generally better to let *java.time* automatically localize.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 1982 , 1 , 24 ) ;
Locale locale = Locale.UK ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = localDate.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/bJnqbS).

> 24 Jan 1982

To calculate age, look for the `LocalDate` related answers on the question: [*How do I calculate someone's age in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116123/642706).

To see if today is their birthday, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

```
MonthDay birthday = MonthDay.from( localDate ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // The time zone through which we want to see today's date.
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.now( z ) ;
if( monthDay.equals( birthday ) ) {  … Happy Birthday … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Thank you! I learnt so much from you and will try it out

Answer (score -1):

Use the Date class. Never deal with dates yourself. Its complicated.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

and here is a simple tutorial

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date

So then you could check if day and month are the same for todays date and then its your birthday

EDIT: As per comments earlier, seems like Date class is no longer cool. Please take a look at the Calendar class

[Java: Why is the Date constructor deprecated, and what do I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-the-date-constructor-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead)

Or even better as Basil mentioned check ouy java.time classes. Although i have never used them before.

Comment: That terrible `Date` class was obsolete years ago, with the adoption of JSR 310 defining the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Oh really? I didnt know. We still use it.

Comment: `Calendar` class only made matters worse. For date-time work, use only classes from the *java.time* packages. JSR 310 was adopted in 2014 — time to move on from `Date`/`Calendar`.

Comment: If it aint broken why fix it

Comment: Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community unanimously decided those classes *were* broken, gave up on them, and adopted *java.time* to supplant them.

Comment: First you write an answer and then you revert it and even point to another answer, so why didn't you simply remove this answer?

Comment: *Never deal with dates yourself. Its complicated.* That’s good advice. I too recommend java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: If you know the answer, then answer it.