# Date and time format in JavaFX

Tags: datetime, javafx

I'm currently working on a JavaFX project and having issues while displaying current date in a text area.
I set the date and time format by using the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh/mm");
Date date = new Date();
```

For example, I want the current date and time to be displayed as 15/05/2021 15:03 but the textarea shows this:

> SAT May 15 15:03:21 PDT 2021

Is there anyway to set date format to "dd/MM/yy hh/mm"?

*NOTE: I imported both java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date.

Comment: Try to avoid the old Date & Time API. Use the `java.time` API added in Java 8 instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`,
> and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` classes were rushed too quickly when
> Java first launched and evolved. The classes were not well designed or
> implemented. Improvements were attempted, thus the deprecations you’ve
> found. Unfortunately the attempts at improvement largely failed. You
> should avoid these classes altogether. They are supplanted in Java 8
> by new classes [(Basil Bourque)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598394/13561971).

Use this instead:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");

TextArea textArea = new TextArea(formatter.format(now));
```