# What is up with javascript Date function for only years?

Tags: javascript, date

(EDIT: I am using chrome console for the code below)

I realize that javascript Date() is deprecated, but it's useful for something I'm currently working on; however there is a strange problem:

```
var x = new Date('999').getFullYear()
```

returns 999

while

```
var x = new Date('1000').getFullYear()
```

returns 999 as well, but

```
var x = new Date('10000').getFullYear()
```

returns 10000...

Does anyone know why do 4 digit numbers give the wrong .getFullYear()?

Comment: Since when is `Date` "deprecated"?  By whom?

Comment: Oops!  I thought I read that while I researching this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460423/why-was-new-dateint-year-int-month-int-day-deprecated, I guess I misunderstood it...

Comment: Date parses the string as a UTC date, but since you are in specific time zone, `new Date('1000')` is maybe on the 31th of December in your time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers suggest, you can't rely on `Date.parse` across browsers, especially if you are dealing with dates before 1000 CE.

As far as Chrome is concerned, it looks like the issue is how the browser deals with timezones. The following example suggests that before 1000 CE, Chrome parses the date in your local timezone on top of it; >= 1000 CE, it appears to first parse the  date in UTC, then applies the timezone conversion:

```
> new Date('1000')
"Tue Dec 31 999 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"
> new Date('999')
"Tue Jan 01 999 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"
```

I'd be inclined to see this as a bug, but perhaps the Chromium team thinks it's a feature :).

The bottom line is that, if you want accurate date parsing for years, especially ancient years, you need to do some work yourself and/or use a library. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) both might help, but I doubt either deals well with ancient years. Moment.js seems to have the same issue (in Chrome):

```
> moment('999').year()
999
> moment('1000').year()
999
```

The best way I know of to accurately set dates based on ancient years is generally to a) always use UTC, and b) set the date manually:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCFullYear('999');
d.getUTCFullYear(); // 999
d.setUTCFullYear('1000');
d.getUTCFullYear(); // 1000
```

In Chrome at least, this works with both strings and integers.

You might also be interested in the [`gregorian` parser in the Timemap.js library](https://code.google.com/p/timemap/source/browse/trunk/src/timemap.js#2613), which handles ancient years with AD, CE, BC, and BCE extensions, as well as negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [at this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  You are passing a string which is passed to this [parse method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).  The first argument isn't "years" unless you pass 3 integers.  Finally while the class itself isn't being deprecated, some of it's members are (including `getYear()` which is being replaced with `getFullYear()` which you are using`)

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtUR7/)  says otherwise on Firefox. Perhaps it's browser related?

Comment: Oh, but Date('999').getFullYear returns a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

`alert(new Date('999').getFullYear());` yields `NaN` on Firefox 15.0.1

Hmm.. Chrome 21.0.1180.57 does yield '999'

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = new Date('10000').getFullYear()
```

change it to

```
var x = new Date(10000).getFullYear()
```

you are sending an `invalid datestring` to the date constructor.

Comment: Your fixed JavaScript will interpret the value 10,000 as milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)

Comment: yes I am suggesting to pass some millisecond(a valid value) than to some invalid date.

Comment: I see, I was interpreting the OP's question as expecting to pass a year in and get a year back, which I could be wrong about.